# Rust match on number condition

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

I have the following match condition that tests whether the entered guess is a valid number (it's from the rust guessing game exercise) :

```
let mut guess = String::new(); 
io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to read");
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_)  => continue,
};
```

How do I extend the match to check if the number is negative or 0 (I want to throw an error in this case) and proceed normally if the number is positive ?

I tried adding an if on the num inside the Ok case, but that throws an error (probably because num is bound to the value of guess) and also doesn't seem idiomatic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `match` arm can be [guarded](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#guards):

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) if num > 0 => num,
    Ok(num) => return Err(whatever),
    Err(_)  => continue,
};
```

Comment: I have quick doubt. My case for negative (the second Ok) doesn't work when I pass a negative number. I keep getting the Err(_) condition instead. Is this because the parse doesn't work for negative number as a string or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: But you parse it as a `u32`, that can't be negative anyway so you will get a parse error. Isn't that what you want?